# JSDoc - How to document an object of methods?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I document this object using JSDoc?

```
/**
  @todo What @type should I use?
  @readonly
*/
export default Object.freeze({
   cannotPlay() {
     ...
   },
});
```

I don't know which type should I use for this.

`@type {object<Function>}` ??

Comment: I noticed that you tagged [tag:typescript]. What is not being inferred that you want to be included? Can you describe more literally what you mean when you use the phrase "How can I document"? What kind of result do you want?

Comment: I wanna add a type for the object. But.. I have seen some people documenting this kind of code (object with methods) as a namespace. So, I don't know whats the correct way (an object of functions or a namespace)